# no wavy error red line show up under the codes in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

i follow a react course but the problem is when i have errors in vscode it alert me about error and its line in the terminal but error red underline dosent show up

i need to see the red underline error location
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i find the solution
the "ESLint" extension need to be installed